# JIRAでテストステップをcsvファイルからアップロードする方法

Tags: csv, テスト

JIRAでテストステップをcsvファイルからアップロードする方法はわかりますか？？
テストケースならアップロードできるのですが・・・

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/84158

Comment: これも私が質問したものです、ありがとうございます

Answer (score 0):

[Zephyr for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.thed.zephyr.je/cloud/overview?_ga=2.53905583.626244524.1499946966-388385865.1499946966)というプラグインがあるみたいですが、これを使えないですかね？

[このページ](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/how-to-export-and-import-test-cases-in-Jira/qaq-p/77011)でも同様の質問があり、Zephyrの名前があがっていました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！zephyrのダウンロードができないのですが、なんとかトライしてみます！